# How can I create an abstract syntax tree considering '|'? (Ply / Yacc)

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, ply

Considering the following grammar:

```
expr : expr '+' term | expr '-' term | term
term : term '*' factor | term '/' factor | factor
factor : '(' expr ')' | identifier | number
```

This is my code using ply:

```
from ply import lex, yacc

tokens = [
    "identifier",
    "number",
    "plus",
    "minus",
    "mult",
    "div"
]

t_ignore = r" \t"
t_identifier = r"^[a-zA-Z]+$"
t_number = r"[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?"
t_plus = r"\+"
t_minus = r"-"
t_mult = r"\*"
t_div = r"/"

def p_stmt(p):
    """stmt : expr"""
    p[0] = ("stmt", p[1])

def p_expr(p):
    """expr : expr plus term 
            | expr minus term 
            | term"""
    p[0] = ("expr", p[1], p[2]) # Problem here <<<

def p_term(p):
    """term : term mult factor 
            | term div factor 
            | factor"""

def p_factor(p):
    """factor : '(' expr ')' 
              | identifier 
              | number"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lex.lex()
    yacc.yacc()
    data = "32 + 10"
    result = yacc.parse(data)
    print(result)
```

How am I supposed to build an AST with the expression if I can't access the operators? I could separate the functions like p_expr_plus, but in this case, I would eliminate operator precedence. The [docs](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) are not so helpful, since I'm a beginner and can't solve this problem. The best material I've found on the subject [is this](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/PLYTalk.pdf), but it does not consider the complexity of operator precedence.

EDIT: I can't access p[2](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/PLYTalk.pdf) or p[3], since I get an IndexError (It's matching the term only). In the PDF I've linked, they explicitly put the operator inside the tuple, like: ('+', p[1](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html), p[2](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/PLYTalk.pdf)), and thus, evincing my problem considering precedence (I can't separate the functions, the expression is the expression, there should be a way to consider the pipes and access any operator).

Comment: I don't understand why you feel that you "can't separate the functions" because of precedence. There is no problem with precedence. You don't use precedence, really; the grammar is unambiguous and operator precedence is inherent in the grammar. Dividing a non-terminal between two different action functions does not change the grammar, and produces simpler actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, in `p[0] = ("expr", p[1], p[2])`, `p[1]` would be the left hand expression, `p[2]` would be the operator, and `p[3]` (that you aren't using) would be the right hand term.

Just use `p[2]` to determine the operator, add `p[3]`, since you will need it, and you should be good to go.

Also, you must verify how many items `p` has, since if the last rule, `| term"""` is matched, `p` will only have two items instead of four.

Take a look at a snippet from the [GardenSnake example:](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/master/example/GardenSnake/GardenSnake.py)

```
def p_comparison(p):
    """comparison : comparison PLUS comparison
                  | comparison MINUS comparison
                  | comparison MULT comparison
                  | comparison DIV comparison
                  | comparison LT comparison
                  | comparison EQ comparison
                  | comparison GT comparison
                  | PLUS comparison
                  | MINUS comparison
                  | power"""
    if len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = binary_ops[p[2]]((p[1], p[3]))
    elif len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = unary_ops[p[1]](p[2])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]
```

Comment: The problem is that when I use p[3], I get a list index out of range. The operator is not considered. In the PDF I've linked, they "save" the operator explicitly: ('+', p[1], p[2]). The problem with this, is that it could be any operator, and I need to consider precedence.

Comment: Oh, right. It must be because of the last line,`| term"""`: when this last rule is matched, `p` will only have two items instead of four.

Comment: That's weird, since "32 + 10" should match "expr plus term", since both expr and term end up being a number.

Comment: Innitially, yes, but note that the rule is recursive, so `expr` will be matched again, for "32", which matches the last rule. I would recommend either putting a breakpoint or a log on the start of the function, so that you can better understand what I mean.

Comment: Oh, I see now with your example... I was seeing the end of the recursion (So obvious, somehow I forgot the basic principle there). Thank you!